# Unhandled exception at 0x012B1CA9

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am new to C++ and am trying to build a simple program that with the users input to proceed will generate a random left or right. I had the program working correctly until I added in the array to try and store each item as I have to output them as soon and the user would like to exit the loop. The program seems to compile fine but at run time I receive "Unhandled exception at 0x012B1CA9" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int userSelection = 1;
const int MAX = '100';
int randNum(0);
int one (0);
int two (0);
int total(0);
int sel[MAX];

do
{
    cout << "Press 1 to pick a side or 0 to quit: ";
    cin >> userSelection;



    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        sel[i] = 1 + (rand() % 2);

        if (sel[i] == 1)
        {
            cout << "<<<--- Left" << endl;
            one++;
            total++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Right --->>>" << endl;
            two++;
            total++;
        }
    }


} while (userSelection == 1);

cout << "Replaying Selections" << endl;
for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
{
    cout << sel[j] << endl;
}

cout << "Printing Statistics" << endl;
double total1 = ((one / total)*100);
double total2 = ((two / total)*100);
cout << "Left: " << one << "-" << "(" << total1 << "%)" << endl;
cout << "Right: " << two << "-" << "(" << total2 << "%)" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
};
```

Comment: I wonder why your compiler didn't complain of `const int MAX = '100';`

Comment: I'm not sure I am using Visual Studio 2015. What should the syntax be?

Comment: `const int MAX = 100;`

Comment: Also, you first for loop starts at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multi-character constant here... and the behavior doesn't go as expected...

Change this line

```
const int MAX = '100';
```

to

```
const int MAX = 100;
```

Note the removed single quotes.

And secondly, I will advice you to remove the Seed of the C random generator from the for loop because, you'll likely get the same values from the `rand()` if you always call it immediately after seeding...

But preferable use the algorithm from [C++'s random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Here is a corrected version of your original code....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int userSelection = 1;
const int MAX = 100;     // <---changed
int randNum(0);
int one (0);
int two (0);
int total(0);
int sel[MAX];

do
{
    cout << "Press 1 to pick a side or 0 to quit: ";
    cin >> userSelection;


    srand(time(NULL));    //< moved to here
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)     // <-- modified starting index
    {
        sel[i] = 1 + (rand() % 2);

        if (sel[i] == 1)
        {
            cout << "<<<--- Left" << endl;
            one++;
            total++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Right --->>>" << endl;
            two++;
            total++;
        }
    }


} while (userSelection == 1);

cout << "Replaying Selections" << endl;
for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
{
    cout << sel[j] << endl;
}

cout << "Printing Statistics" << endl;
double total1 = ((one / total)*100);
double total2 = ((two / total)*100);
cout << "Left: " << one << "-" << "(" << total1 << "%)" << endl;
cout << "Right: " << two << "-" << "(" << total2 << "%)" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
};
```

Comment: He's also 1-based indexing his first loop, which he might want to correct.

Comment: Thank you this resolved the error. I am noticing that it seems the array is not storing all of the numbers. Do you have an idea of why?

Comment: @kfsone Would it be better if my rand was 0-1 instead of 1-2?

Comment: @CameronAbel I'm refering to this: `for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)`. This means you don't populate the 1st element of sel (sel[0]). Personally I wouldn't have added the +1 to the rand result, I'd have made 0 left and 1 right. But that's opinion and not policy :)

Comment: @kfsone That makes sense and would cause an issue as below in the Replaying Sections I started at 0. How ever that is still not functioning. It seems to be writing only writing one item to the array.

Comment: @CameronAbel Yes, your while loop causes the entire array to be overwritten every time, but according to this - http://ideone.com/k4cDZX - (I reduced MAX to 10 for simplicity) it appears to be workingish. It's just odd that you have the while loop around the for loop.

Comment: @ kfsone, So looking at your page you provided it looks like it is writing to the array but it isn't supposed to iterate through but once until the user selects 1 again. I added a break at the bottom of the for statement and it functions correctly but my output after isn't correct. Maybe the way I am implementing this isn't be best way to go about it. See http://postimg.org/image/48e37hrsn/

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is basically good idea to read more about C data types and declaration. Your error:

`const int MAX = '100'` should be `const int MAX = 100` without any quotes. C++ does implicit conversion from character literals to `int`.